# Why am I not seeing encryption as an option in file roller?

Tags: encryption, compression

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I've done:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

...but when I launch file roller, I don't see any encryption options and the UI seems very basic.

Comment: Tried from CLI also.  No errors. This is to say that I executed "file-roller".

Comment: Trying reinstall... Nope. Same result.

Comment: I get enough to work with if I launch it against a file already created and I can encrypt a *.zip file already created but when launched by itself and used as a management UI, it's basically useless.

Comment: Yep, but maybe not till this evening. I can get it to work with *.zip if I finagle around with it a bit but not *.7z which seems to have been working in the past. Strangely, you have to apply the encryption AFTER you create the file.

Comment: OK, I've figured this out. It was me. The new OS Dock and UI where what was throwing me.

Comment: Consider posting an answer below by clicking "answer your question" button to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Archive Manager (file-roller) have these options. Rt. click and Open with Archive Manager.

To extract you can drag and drop.

Can be used to encrypt as well as decrypt.

[image: file-roller]

[image: file-roller-2]

Answer (score 0):

OK so this UI is a bit strange. You have to "Create an Archive" first using the menu. Then you can do pretty much what ever you want.